How select query from record count more than 2 with custom column (Option) via linq with VB.NET
I'm trying to select query from row count more than 2 based on ID and DATE with custom column (Option) via  linq with VB.NET
so with "NO" in the option column then the record more than 2 is not included in my sql query code.
it is not more than 2 records with the help column OPTION` The purpose of the option column with the value 'NO' is to declare that the record is not selected again in the record more than 2 so for example 5009 with date 29-Apr-24 this includes record more 2 so if one of my records uses the option column with 'NO' then the status of record more 2 it means lost.
And one more I want to calculate the sum count of the more 2 records so it appears in the textbox as per the code I posted below. I want it to be with linq instead of doing calculations in the datagridview
Please Guide me
So I think it's easier if it's applied via linq
Thanks
Table Absen



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
OPTION




5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
0
OUT



5045
21-Jun-24
08:16:10
IN



5045
21-Jun-24
17:04:45
OUT



5045
22-Jun-24
08:18:14
IN



5045
21-May-24
08:19:25
IN



5045
21-May-24
17:04:40
OUT
NO


5008
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5008
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT
NO


5010
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT




Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5008
A
STAFF


5009
B
STAFF


5010
C
STAFF


5011
D
STAFF


5045
E
STAFF



Code In VB.NET
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class Form1
    Dim ABSENService As New ABSENService()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim CheckCountdoublerecordabsen = ABSENService.CheckCountdoublerecordabsen()
        TextBox1.Text = CheckCountdoublerecordabsen.Expr1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ABSENService.GetDoubleFP()
        DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ABSENDOUBLEFP
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property NAMEID As String
    Public Property POSITIONID As String
    Public Property [DATE] As DateTime
    Public Property TIME As String

    <DisplayName("IN/OUT")>
    Public Property INOUT As String
End Class

Public Class ABSENService
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ABSEN.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function

    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()

    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDoubleFP() As IEnumerable(Of ABSENDOUBLEFP)
        Dim sql2 = "SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT,MASTERID.POSITIONID
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE a.option is null and exists(select a.ID from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID and a.DATE=a2.DATE group by a.ID,a.DATE having count(*) > 2)
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ABSENDOUBLEFP)(sql2).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function CheckCountdoublerecordabsen() As ABSENDOUBLEFP
        Dim sql = $"SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 FROM ABSEN INNER JOIN MASTERID ON MASTERID.ID = ABSEN.ID WHERE ABSEN.OPTION Is Null HAVING Count(ABSEN.ID AND ABSEN.DATE)>2;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ABSENDOUBLEFP)(sql).ToList().First()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class

Result code in screenshot

Desired result
The value that appears in the textbox based on the results of the record below is 7



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5011
D
STAFF
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
STAFF
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
STAFF
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5045
E
STAFF
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN


5045
E
STAFF
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN


5045
E
STAFF
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN


5045
E
STAFF
12-Jul-24
0
OUT



